# List all smartcard slots in Java

Tags: java, smartcard, pkcs#11

How can I search through all available slots in the machine so I can get each keystore for each slot, in Java?

Comment: As I've found just now, I can do that.

Comment: thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549633/java-how-to-detect-smartcard-hotplug

Comment: I just added a plus to that question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I've found, there is this a way:

```
PKCS11 p11 = PKCS11.getInstance("/usr/local/lib/libsiecap11.so", "C_GetFunctionList", null, false); 
long[] slots = p11.C_GetSlotList(true);
```

thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549633/java-how-to-detect-smartcard-hotplug)

Comment: And from where do you get the PKCS11 class?

Comment: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11

Comment: Headsup: this won't work in Java 9 due to the module system.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a very precise question.

If you are not precise, then the "most probable" solution is 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/security/smartcardio/spec/javax/smartcardio/CardTerminals.html

But you seem to be talking about PKCS#11 (which is NOT the direct mapping of a smart card hardware "slot")

Comment: If you check the tags, you will see that it has pkcs11 in it. Not a bad question at all

Comment: Please notice who added the pkcs11 tag (me)

Answer (score 0):

Write JNI code in C++ and call it from java.